# Undo revision to a topic in documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I've been trying to familiarize myself with the new documentation feature and I came across [some documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/comprehensions/1474/avoiding-repeating-expensive-operations#t=201607220823416849512) that I believe to be incorrect.  I was able see the revision where the incorrect information was added and -- in this case -- the entire revision is incorrect.

Is there a supported way to roll-back an incorrect revision or should I just edit the topic again and remove the incorrect information?